How can I make my Flutter program to run faster in Android Studio? It takes too long to run a simple Program
enter image description here
I’m using Android Studio to develop Flutter applications, but my programs take too long to run, even for simple projects. My laptop has an AMD Ryzen 5 4500 processor and 16 GB of RAM. How can I optimize the performance to make my Flutter programs run faster?
Here are the steps I’ve tried:
Upgraded Flutter and Dart: I ensured that I’m using the latest stable versions of Flutter and Dart.
Increased Virtual Device RAM: I increased the allocated RAM for my Android Virtual Device (AVD) to 2048 MB.
Cold Boot: I set the emulator to perform a cold boot instead of a quick boot.
Disabled Unnecessary Plugins: I disabled plugins in Android Studio that I don’t use.
Enabled Hardware Acceleration: I enabled hardware acceleration in the emulator settings.
Clean and Rebuild Project: I regularly run flutter clean and rebuild my project.
Android Studio Performance Settings: I adjusted the memory settings in Android Studio to allocate more RAM (4096 MB) to the IDE.
Despite these efforts, the performance is still sluggish. Are there any additional steps or configurations I can try to improve the run speed of my Flutter applications on Android Studio? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
